# Is a stored procedure with EXECUTE AS OWNER a valid replacement for a view selecting from third-schema tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, ownership

A database user **A** should only have access to specific data.
This data is currently provided by a view **B.VIEW1** selecting from tables owned by schema **B** and **C**.

```
CREATE VIEW [B].[VIEW1] AS SELECT * FROM [B].[VIEW2], [C].[VIEW1]
```

Since **C.VIEW1** is not owned by **B**, [Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) apply.

That means although **A** is granted *SELECT* permission ON **B.VIEW1**, it can't select from.

```
SELECT permission denied on object 'C.VIEW1', database '...', schema '...'.
```

Is a stored procedure **B.PROC1** with [*EXECUTE AS OWNER Clause*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) a valid replacement for **B.VIEW1** in terms of security?

```
CREATE PROC [B.PROC1] WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM [B.VIEW2], [C].[VIEW1] END
```

Or are there any negative side-effects which will possibly lead to any security problems?

Comment: Discussions facing this question: [SQL Server: How to permission schemas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509525/sql-server-2008-schema-separation-and-permissions?rq=1), [Sql Server 2008 schema separation and permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509525/sql-server-2008-schema-separation-and-permissions?rq=1), [Managing Permissions with Stored Procedures in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669058.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In terms of security, this seems to be a [good way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669058.aspx) to prevent access to underlying tables.

A negative side-effect is that you can't filter the resultset generated by the stored procedure by a WHERE, GROUP BY clause or similar.

But this is not that tragic if defining static constraints in an underlying view
or defining "dynamic" constraints via [stored proc's input parameters](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7132).

1) Static constraints in underlying view

```
CREATE VIEW [B].[VIEW3] AS SELECT * FROM [B].[VIEW2], [C].[VIEW1] WHERE [X]='Something' AND [Y] = GETDATE()
CREATE PROC [B].[PROC1] WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM [B].[VIEW3] END
```

2) Dynamic constraints via input parameters

```
CREATE PROC [B].[PROC1] (@X varchar(30), @Y DATETIME) WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM [B].[VIEW2], [C].[VIEW1] WHERE [X]=@X AND [Y]=@Y AND
```